# Memory leak in F# async recursive call

Tags: asynchronous, memory-leaks, f#, tail-recursion

I'm confused why this function shows memory constantly increasing

```
let rec startRead1() = 
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep 1
    System.GC.Collect()
    let mem = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true)
    printfn "%d" mem
    do! startRead1()
  }
```

25676
36760
36840
36884
36928
36972
37016
37060
37104
37148
37192
37236
37280
37324
37368
37412
37456
37500
37544
37588
37632
37676
37720
37764
37808
37852
37896
37940
37984
38028
38072
38116
38160
38204
38248
38292
38336
38380
38424
38468
38512
38556
38600
38644
38688
38732
38776
38820
38864
38908
38952
38996
39040
39084
39128
39172
39216
^CPress any key to continue . . .

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 
  startRead1() |> Async.RunSynchronously
  0
```

Whereas this one shows stable memory

```
let rec startRead2() = 
  async {
    while true do
      do! Async.Sleep 1
      System.GC.Collect()
      let mem = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true)
      printfn "%d" mem
  }
```

The synchronous version is stable too.

```
let rec startRead3() = 
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 1
  System.GC.Collect()
  let mem = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true)
  printfn "%d" mem
  startRead3()
```

I'm running in release mode without debugger attached, FS 3.1, .NET 4.5.1.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quoted from [here](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/) (end of article) :

> "*Also, F# async has its problems too (the most common gotcha is that tail-recursive functions must use `return!` instead of `do!` to avoid leaks)*"

Comment: Gah, now if only FS power tools had a quick way to find all recursive async functions in my solution...I must have this error a dozen times at least!  Took me a day to distill the crash down to a leak down to async down to a single reproduceable function.